# Rails NoMethodError when calling a model method from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I want to call a method from my controller and am receiving a NoMethodError: undefined method `combine_table_lines' for Data:Class

I am new to rails, so I apologize if this is something very basic.

Controller: data_controller.rb

```
class DataController < ApplicationController

  def abetReport
     @slos = Answer.joins(knowledge_topic: :student_learning_outcomes).select( 
             'student_learning_outcomes.title', :is_correct, "count(answers.id) AS  
              total_answers").group('student_learning_outcomes.id', :is_correct)
     @slos_combined = Data.combine_table_lines(@slos) 


  end
end
```

Model: data.rb

```
class Data

  def self.combine_table_lines(data)
     #body of method 
  end # end method

end
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Data` is a reserved word:

http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words

Have you tried renaming the class?